# How do I use a condition on a dictionary array to pull elements from another array in the same dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of arrays.

```
mydict={'a':[45,65,78,32], 'b':['red','blue','green','yellow'], 'c':[3.4, 4.5, 6.5, 7.6]}
```

I want to pull the elements of `mydict['b']` when `mydict['a']` is greater than `35`. I want

```
myarr = ['red','blue','green']
```

I tried -

```
myarr = [mydict['b'] for num in mydict['a'] num > 35]
```

I do not want to go the C++/C route of enumerating and saving the index and using the index. Not Sounds like Python.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new `list` if the val of `dict['a'] > 35`:

```
mydict = {'a':[45,65,78,32], 'b':['red','blue','green','yellow'], 'c':[3.4, 4.5, 6.5, 7.6]}
```

**Python 3.x**:

Using [`itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
>   with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
>   exhausted

```
print([y for x,y in zip_longest(mydict['a'],mydict['b']) if x > 35])
```

**Python 2.x**:

Using [`itertools.izip_longest(*iterables[, fillvalue])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

```
print([y for x,y in izip_longest(mydict['a'],mydict['b']) if x > 35])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

**EDIT**:

What is the difference between `zip()` and `zip_longest()`?

Consider the following lists:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]    
y = ['a','b','c']

for a,b in zip(x,y):
    print(a,b)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

It clearly skipped the elements `4,5` in the `x` since it could not find its correspondings in the `y`.

Using `zip_longest()`:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]    
y = ['a','b','c']

for a,b in zip_longest(x,y):
    print(a,b)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 None
5 None
```

It did not skip the elements in the `x`, instead filled the missing ones in the y with a `None`.

Comment: Could you also add a note about the differences between ```zip``` and ```zip_longest```?

Answer (score 3):

you're close, you need to use `zip`:

```
[b for a, b in zip(mydict['a'], mydict['b']) if a > 35]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to access the corresponding index `i` using which you can get the corresponding value from `mydict['b']`.

```
myarr = [mydict['b'][i]  for i, num in enumerate(mydict['a']) if num > 35]
# ['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Comment: *I do not want to go the C++/C route of enumerating and saving the index and using the index.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[j for i,j in zip(mydict['a'],mydict['b']) if i>35]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using `pandas`, this type of filtering is quite easy.

First pass `mydict` to the DataFrame constructor:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
print(df)
#    a       b    c
#0  45     red  3.4
#1  65    blue  4.5
#2  78   green  6.5
#3  32  yellow  7.6
```

Now  use a [boolean mask to filter the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) that meet your condition:

```
print(df[df['a']>35])
#    a      b    c
#0  45    red  3.4
#1  65   blue  4.5
#2  78  green  6.5
```

To get your desired output as a list, you can do:

```
myarr = df[df['a']>35]['b'].values.tolist()
print(myarr)
#['red', 'blue', 'green']
```